# Printing " (double quote) in C

Tags: c, printf, double-quotes, quote

I am writing a C code which reads from a file and generates an intermediate `.c` file.
To do so I use `fprintf()` to print into that intermediate file.

How can I print `"` ?

Comment: `printf("\"");`

Comment: You probably should build some [AST](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_syntax_tree) before emitting it as generated C code.

Comment: C isn't exactly the language you want to use to generate code. While possible, and certainly adequate if complex computations have to be done to generate simple code, it's generally a job for a preprocessor. Stuff like m4 has been used quite effectively. Many people use python for this purpose. But which is best really depends on the problem at hand.

Comment: `fputc('"', fp);` works too, or using `%c` with `fprintf`, but escaping in a string literal is usually simplest.

Comment: You probably should not have mentioned your motivation, as all the religious nuts will pounce on that and ignore your question.

Comment: This is a pretty good summary: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_sequences_in_C

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use escape symbol `\"` For example

```
puts( "\"This is a sentence in quotes\"" );
```

or

```
printf( "Here is a quote %c", '\"' );
```

or

```
printf( "Here is a quote %c", '"' );
```

Comment: 中文(Chinese)：

你可以使用溢出符號 \" ，例如：puts( "\"這是在雙引號中的句子\"" );
或是 printf( "這是一個雙引號 %c", '\"' ); 或是 printf( "這是一個雙引號 %c", '"' );

Comment: IMHO the second one is the best

Answer (score 6):

If you just want to print a single `"` character:

```
putchar('"');
```

The `"` doesn't have to be escaped in a character constant, since character constants are delimited by `'`, not `"`. (You can still escape it if you like: `'\"'`.)

If it's part of some larger chunk of output in a string literal, you need to escape it so it's not treated as the closing `"` of the literal:

```
puts("These are \"quotation marks\"");
```

or

```
printf("%s\n", "These are \"quotation marks\"");
```