# Can anyone give me some explanations about fprintf('How about single quote('')?\n') in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, io, printf

```
>> fprintf('How about single quote('')?\n')
How about single quote(')?
```

the output is the same as:

```
>> fprintf("How about single quote(\')?\n")
How about single quote(')?
```

which is more general to comprehend
(Escape character is composed of a backslash'\' and a character(e.g. 'n'))

So, is a backslash('\') can be altered by a single quote( ' ) to represent escape character in MATLAB?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Matlab has [*char vectors* and *strings*](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/characters-and-strings.html). They are different data types. Char vectors are enclosed with single quotes (`'`):

```
disp('This is a char vector')
```

whereas strings use double quoutes (`"`):

```
disp("Hey, I am a string")
```

To introduce a single quote in a char vector, or a double quote in a string, you *duplicate* it:

```
disp('Hey, what''s up?')
disp("Say ""Hi""")
```

Introducing a double quote in a char vector, or a single quote in a string, poses no problem:

```
disp('She said "yes"')
disp("What's the matter?")
```

All this applies normally when the char vectors or strings are used as arguments to `fprintf`. Additionally, Matlab's `fprintf` and `sprintf` *apparently*<sup>1</sup> understand `\'` as synonymous of `'`, and `\"` as synonymous of `"`; but the duplication rules still apply.<sup>2</sup> So these are equivalent:

```
fprintf('I don''t like strings\n')
fprintf('I don\''t like strings\n')
```

as are these:

```
fprintf("""Inconceivable!"", he retorted\n")
fprintf("\""Inconceivable!\"", he retorted\n")
```

Outside of `fprintf` or `sprintf`, `\'` and `\"` don't have those special meanings. Try

```
disp('\'' \"')
disp("\' \""")
```

---

<sub><sup>1</sup>
I haven't been able to find this documented.


<sup>2</sup>
The reason is probably to mimic [C's `fprintf` behaviour](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25411644/printing-double-quote-in-c); but note that no duplication is needed there.</sub>

Comment: @Hua-MingHuang My pleasure!